# Nonsensical "Service has leaked ServiceConnection" messages

Tags: java, android, android-service, aidl, android-service-binding

I am encountering some really strange behavior with bound services. I am getting the following error message with a stack trace pointing to where i am calling `bindService()`.

```
Service com.sample.myapp.components.service.MyService has leaked ServiceConnection com.sample.myapp.erased.MyClassName$1@143da1e7 that was originally bound here
android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.sample.myapp.components.service.MyService has leaked ServiceConnection com.sample.myapp.erased.MyClassName$1@143da1e7 that was originally bound here
    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:1077)
    ...
```

I understand that this message usually means that you forgot to call `unbindService()`, but this is not the case. For every `bindService()`, I DO have an `unbindService()`.

This is the log output from my tests:

```
08-20 05:42:53.647 29070-29149/com.sample.myapp W/AIDL-DEBUG: BOUND service 87851412
08-20 05:42:53.649 29070-29149/com.sample.myapp I/<hidden>: com.aaa.ccc returned true from myBoolMethod()
08-20 05:42:53.652 29070-29149/com.sample.myapp W/AIDL-DEBUG: UN-BOUND service 87851412
08-20 05:42:53.674 29070-29070/com.sample.myapp E/ActivityThread: Service com.sample.myapp.components.service.MyService has leaked ServiceConnection com.sample.myapp.erased.MyClassName$1@143da1e7 that was originally bound here
android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.sample.myapp.components.service.MyService has leaked ServiceConnection com.sample.myapp.erased.MyClassName$1@143da1e7 that was originally bound here
...
```

My code runs in an IntentService, so it runs on its own thread and I am using `ConditionVariable` to wait for `onServiceConnected()` to be called, then i am calling `myBoolMethod()` and then `unbindService()`.

What could the issue be?

Comment: In my experience most of the time the `code` is right when it throws an exception. However without a code example, ideally a [mre], we can't point out where the issue may be.